# How to enable the enhanced ecommerce tracking using GTM and GA4 knowing that my website was created with Odoo?

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-datalayer, enhanced-ecommerce

I am not at all in the IT field. However, my employer recently asked me to set up his website on Google Tag Manager. The goal is to be able to retrieve ecommerce data from the website in order to send them to Google Analytics. To do this, I believe I have to create a datalayer and insert it in the source code of the website pages. Being a total beginner and having just started using Google Tag Manager, I'm wondering how to proceed to do this?

I saw that there were several ways to create a datalayer: by hiring a developer or by using plugins.

As I am not a developer I rather opt for the use of a plugin. I have seen that there was a plugin for wordpress to create a datalayer to retrieve data from the website. However, I work on Odoo. I was therefore wondering if there was an equivalent plugin for Odoo?

In case it is not possible to do it via a plugin in Odoo, how do I proceed to create the datalayer manually?

In summary, I would like to know what are the steps to follow to track the ecommerce of my website using GA4 and GTM knowing that my website has been created with Odoo?

I have no idea how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Before we start, tracking implementation is a software development-related job. This should be conveyed to your boss. The optimal course here is to hire a contractor who would implement tracking and test it thoroughly. Without knowledge and experience, you would be very lucky to implement it properly in reasonable amount of time.

Now, looks like there are paid modules for this for Odoo. [Here](https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/15.0/website_sale_google_analytics_4/), the first I stumbled upon. So development intervention may not be needed.

After you have it, you will need to install GTM and create EEC tags in GTM. [Here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/ecommerce?client_type=gtm) are the instructions, but they may not be extremely helpful since they presume some level of development experience.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please resend me the link of the plugin that you recommended because the one in your answer doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. Fixed the link.